# transfer result to input from p tag

Tags: javascript

i have this code, Age auto change when the birth day is given but my problem i cant figure out how to put it in input field, I just want to change P tag into input tag but the it's not working when i change it.

```js
function submitBday() {
  var Bdate = document.getElementById('bday').value;
  var Bday = +new Date(Bdate);
  Q4A = ~~((Date.now() - Bday) / (31557600000));
  var theBday = document.getElementById('resultBday');
  theBday.innerHTML = Q4A;
}
```

```html
<p id="resultBday"></p>
<input type="date" name="BirthDate" id="bday" onchange="submitBday()">
```

Comment: «I just want to change P tag into input tag» (¬_¬ ) `.innerHTML` → `.value` ?

Comment: your my saviour thank you so much